# Comprehension Flow, is making me slow

Tags: elixir

I have a large `map` where I am creating combinations using a comprehension, then filtering the combinations...

```
for a <- data[:a],
    b <- data[:b],
    c <- data[:c],
    reducer(a ++ b ++ c) <= @limit do
      a ++ b ++ c
    end
```

As far as I know, this is not done in parallel and only utilizes one core(?)

So, I wanted to add `Flow` to this so that as the combinations are created, they can be filtered in parallel.

Below is a module consisting of 3 functions:

- `CompFlow.no_flow`: No flow, just uses a comprehension
- `CompFlow.enum_flow`: Creates an `Enum` using a comprehension, then filters using a flow
- `CompFlow.stream_flow`: Creates combinations as a `Stream` and filters them in a flow as they are created...I think

**I thought that each of these functions should be faster than the next, but the opposite is true...** `no_flow` is an order of magnitude faster than `enum_flow` which is several orders of magnitude faster than `stream_flow`.

I obviously have a fundamental misunderstanding as to how I am trying to apply flows...could someone please explain what I am doing wrong here and if what I am trying to do (speed up my comprehension) is possible?

Full module:

```elixir
defmodule CompFlow do
  @moduledoc false

  require Logger

  @limit 9
  @data %{
    :a => [
      [{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}],
      [{5, "w"}, {4, "x"}],
      [{1, "y"}, {3, "z"}]
    ],
    :b => [
      [{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}],
      [{3, "i"}, {3, "j"}],
      [{2, "e"}, {1, "f"}]
    ],
    :c => [
      [{1, "g"}],
      [{3, "s"}],
      [{3, "v"}]
    ]
  }

  @doc """
  Create and filter combos with a comprehension.
  """
  def no_flow(data \\ @data) do
    Logger.info "Starting to create combos"
    combos = for a <- data[:a],
                 b <- data[:b],
                 c <- data[:c],
                 reducer(a ++ b ++ c) <= @limit do
                   a ++ b ++ c
                 end
    Logger.info "Combos created"
  end

  @doc """
  Create all combos, then filter the resulting
  `Emun` using a `Flow`.
  """
  def enum_flow(data \\ @data) do
    Logger.info "Starting to create combos"
    combos = for a <- data[:a],
                 b <- data[:b],
                 c <- data[:c] do
                   a ++ b ++ c
                 end

    filtered_combos = combos
    |> Flow.from_enumerable()
    |> Flow.partition()
    |> Flow.reduce(fn -> [] end,
                   fn x, acc ->
                     if reducer(x) <= @limit do
                       acc ++ [x]
                     else
                       acc
                     end
                   end)
    |> Enum.to_list()
    Logger.info "Combos created"
  end

  @doc """
  Create combos and filter the `Stream` using
  a `Flow`.
  """
  def stream_flow(data \\ @data) do
    Logger.info "Starting to create combos"
    combos = for a <- data[:a],
                 b <- data[:b],
                 c <- data[:c] do
                   [a ++ b ++ c]
                   |> Flow.from_enumerable()
                   |> Flow.partition()
                   |> Flow.reduce(fn -> [] end,
                                  fn x, acc ->
                                    if reducer(x) <= @limit do
                                      acc ++ x
                                    else
                                      acc
                                    end
                                  end)
                   |> Enum.to_list()
                 end
    filtered_combos = Enum.filter(combos, &(length(&1) > 0))
    Logger.info "Combos created"
  end

  defp reducer(enum) do
    Enum.reduce(enum, 0, fn(x, acc) -> elem(x, 0) + acc end)
  end

end
```

Comment: “So, I wanted to add `Flow` to this so that as the combinations are created, they can be filtered in parallel.”—this is called _a premature optimization_ and should be punished in general.

Comment: @mudasobwa this example is a simplification. My real use case has trillions of combinations. I have to limit it to about 30 million, which take about 3-5 minutes. I was looking to improve this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map is too small to get benefits from using Flow. Flow is great when dealing with very large of even indefinite collections, because then you have a boost running the app on several cores. However Flow requires some time to init and the whole action in the background with changing the cores takes also some time, so in your case it's pointless to use it.

You should try to optimize approach with `Enum` module- for such small map, this module will be sufficient. You could change the way you are merging the lists and instead of

```
a ++ b ++ c
```

you could use something more efficient.

Whenever you are using this combined list, you should get it from the variable - not calculate it all the time.

Please [watch more here](https://youtu.be/XPlXNUXmcgE?t=14m51s) about the required overhead for the Flow.

Comment: [`:lists.merge/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#merge-2) requires sorted list as arguments.